# Последний элемент массива

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет, я пишу веб-чат на vue. Дело в том что мне совсем не хватает опыта и знаний и я не могу разобраться в одной вещи. Я отправляю запрос на сервер, и сразу же получаю ответ в виде массива:

```
[ { "user": "debash", "text": "priv", "timestamp": "2022-09-02 10:02:21" }, { "user": "server", "text": "123 теперь в чате", "timestamp": "2022-09-02 10:05:34" } ]
```

я его помещаю в messages и вывожу:

```
<li v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
                <strong>>>> {{ message.user }}: {{message.text }} ({{message.timestamp}})</strong>
</li>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы у меня выводился не весь ответ, а только новые "сообщения".
Нужно сделать это путем запоминания последнего `timestamp`.
Как мне это сделать?

Пример на pythone:

```
i = datetime.strptime("0001-01-01 01:01:00", '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        r = requests.get(f"http://{ser}/getmessages")
        global message
        for message in json.loads(r.text.replace("'", '"')):
            if not message:
                pass
            else:
                timestamp=datetime.strptime(message['timestamp'], '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
                if timestamp > i:
                    print(f">>> {message['user']}: {message['text']} ({message['timestamp']})\n")
                    i = timestamp
                else:
                    pass
```

Comment: А что вы понимаете под новыми сообщениями? Какое кол-во? Опишите подробнее и приведите пример.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси когда юзер пишет сообщение, он отправляет запрос на сервер, сервер хранит эти сообщения у себя и в том числе дата и число отправки сообщений. изначально мы должны задать данные 00:00:00 чтобы при первом входе, нам выходили все сообщения что больше 00:00:00. Мы запоминаем дату последнего сообщения что мы вывели и храним её у себя, если юзер отправит сообщения то соответственно время будет больше чем у последнего сообщения. Пример привел, только на pythone

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вначале отфильтровать(`Array.filter()`) messages по timestamp и удалить все сообщения старше последнего опубликованного сообщения.